# How would one open an iMessage app extension from the hosting application?

Tags: ios, swift, uiapplication, imessage-extension, uiapplicationshortcutitem

I'm trying to open an iMessage extension application from the main hosting extension using `URL` in the following manner,

```
if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url){
  UIApplication.shared.open(url)
}else{
  print("unable to open URL")
}
```

I added the url scheme to the `info.plist` of the iMessage app extension however it doesn't seem to work, and being that an iMessage app is hosted in iMessage would I need to adjust the url scheme to first navigate to iMessage. I appreciate any advice.